# onPress function doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to add multiple function on onPress. So I have onPress function like this. But that doesn't work.

```
  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
      const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: route
      });
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
    }

    onButtonPress() {
      this.navigateToScreen('Home', { isStatusBarHidden: false })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.menuItem}
            onPress={() => {this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
          >
  ...
```

`navigateToScreen` does't work, let me know why.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
onPress={() => this.onButtonPress()}
```

or:

```
onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} // bind in constructor for better performance
```

or:

```
onButtonPress = () => {
...
onPress={this.onButtonPress}
```

Also, your `navigateToScreen` has an extra level of param:

```
navigateToScreen = (route, options) => {
```